# Flutter widget that doesn't occupy any space on screen

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

In flutter I want to use a widget in my application that if the condition is not satisfied a container is printed (or any other widget) that contain no space on the screen.
Actually I want a widget that covers no space on screen in flutter.

Answer (score 5):

Use `SizedBox.shrink()`.

For example:

```
SomeWidget(
  child: boolShow ? YourWidget() : SizedBox.shrink(),
)
```

Comment: Is there an advantage of using `.shrink` rather than than simply using `SizedBox()`?

Comment: @user1032613 `SizedBox.shrink()` sets `width` and `height` to `0` which are initialized `null` by default. Generally speaking, you can use `SizedBox` also instead of `SizedBox.shrink` but using the word `shrink` gives you a clear indication that this widget will occupy the least (or zero) space on the screen. Using a `SizedBox()` could be misunderstood, like did you forget to provide a widget to it?. There could be other cases which I'm not able to think right now.

Comment: That's fair. I read the source code before asking too, initialing the sizes to `null` would be the same since it doesn't a `child` so it'll occupy the smallest space as long as its parent constraints allow. Unless explicitly stating `0` would somehow optimize the layout constraint solver, but I couldn't find any evidences on that, and the layout process is already one-pass. Maybe it just comes down to semantics only...

Answer (score 0):

simply use Container() or SizedBox().
Don't give any height, width or child.

Comment: Container should not be used as it is heavy

Comment: I have used both but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Kindly share your code wherever you want this no space widget.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to do this.

Firstly you can show an empty `SizedBox` with height 0 in case the condition is met. In case the condition is not met show the desired widget. This will look like below:

```
child: if_condition_is_met ? Container(child: ...) : const SizedBox(),
```

If you are applying the condition in a column, you can try the below code.

```
Column(
  children: [
    if(the_condition_is_not_met)
      Container(child: ---- your widgets ---),
  ]
)
```

You can also use `dialog box` to show the message

```
showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
          Radius.circular(20),
        ),
        side: BorderSide(
          color: Colors.black,
          width: 3,
        ),
      ),
      title: Text(
        'give_a_title',
      ),
      content: Text(
        'some_text',
      ),
      actions: [
        SizedBox(
          child: TextButton(
            onPressed: (){},
            child: Text(
              'Ok',
            ),
          ),
        )
      ]
    ),
  );
```